# display specific user plan with users.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm new to ruby and have an app in which users are either "plan_id = 1", or "plan_id = 2".

I have a section which uses:  `<% @users.each do |user| %>` to display all users.

I want to make this page only viewable to users from "plan_id 2", while displaying only users from "Plan_id 1".

Simple I'm sure, but I'm new, so any suggestion is appreciated.

How do I do this?

Comment: can you post schema please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a scope to get users with `plan_id = 1`

**Controller**

```
@users = User.where(plan_id: 1)

# or create a scope

scope premium_users, -> { where(plan_id: 1) }

def your_method
  @users = User.premium_users
  # ...
end
```

Check if current user has plan_id = 2 and then enter the block

**View**

```
<% if current_user.plan_id == 2 %>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    # Your stuff here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Works.  Thank you!